# 2 Svc files, 1 project, both return the same file

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a single C# WCF project.
It has 2 SVC files.  Invoices.svc and Statements.svc.

It compiles and builds without issue.

Statements is inheriting from IStatements, and all methods/results go through a separate Statements name space.

Despite that, when I call the wsdl, against the Statements.svc file, it returns the invoice classes again.

Any reason why a C# project might load a different SVC file than you requested?

I'm stumped.

Comment: I should include: from the webservice url for Statements.svc, it is returning Invoice classes.  The problem appears to be between IIS and the Service project.

Comment: In your client application you already have the Invoices service reference and you try to add a service reference to Statements ?

Comment: The two services are using identical classes as datacontract ? The only difference is the namespace ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have copypasted the svc files, so one svc references the other service class. Check the contents of the svc files.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the services. When you add a service reference, by default WCF will look into your projects and if it finds classes that are identical as properties as the ones from your WSDL will reuse them instead of creating new ones.

If both services have classes with the same properties as DataContract, the second one that you want to add in your client application will use the generated classes for the first one, because they match and can be reused.

To change this behavior (VS 2012 or 2013) you need to do this click Advanced when you add the service reference and select the second radio button "Reuse types in specified referenced assemblies", then check all the system assemblies and don't check your own projects. Then reference will create it's own classes.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the problem in this case, given that the information was somewhat vague to begine with, was not what was suggested so far.

The issue turned out to be the Statements.SVC XML file held a reference to IInvoices.  It was the one file that the solution explorer does not show by default, so I had thought I updated all references, but I did not.

Thank you for your help.  I don't think this question should be deleted, because it does provide the recommendation to check the SVC XML file for references as well.

Thanks.